# Htaccess redirect url with database id

Tags: mysql, apache, .htaccess, web, redirect

I want to redirect this url for each NUMERO in my database:

https://www.website.com/post.php?id=NUMERO

with

https://www.website.com/NUMERO

where NUMERO is the id of a cell in my sql database. For example:

https://www.website.com/post.php?id=7

https://www.website.com/7

To do the redirect I have added in my htaccess file this line:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

But it does not work and I don't undestand why.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: `^/` will never match in a .htaccess file. Remove the slash.

Comment: It does not work anyway!

Comment: Ok but what do you get? 404? Is it your full .htaccess? Does Apache read your .htaccess (`AllowOverride` not valued to `None`)?

Comment: No I don't get anything, yep my .htaccess is full and starts with: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] https works fine, so apache read my .htaccess.

Comment: "I don't get anything" = blank page? If so, a 500 because of a PHP fatal error?

Comment: “I don’t get anything” = the url remain the same and I can see my page without errors.

Comment: "the url remains the same": this is how rewriting works. It's not a redirection so the URL will never change! What's the URL you actually test? Have you changed your links (a href) to /NUMERO? You want to do both, redirect post.php?id=NUMERO to /NUMERO **and** rewrite  /NUMERO to post.php?id=NUMERO?

Comment: Okay, that’s clear! I simply want that the page at the url: www.website.com/post.php?id=NUMERO switch to the url www.website.com/NUMERO. And the url www.website.com/post.php?id=NUMERO does not exist anymore. Where NUMERO is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
# redirect "old" URL (/post.php?id=NUMERO to /NUMERO)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^post\.php$ %1 [L,R=permanent]

# rewrite /NUMERO to /post.php?id=NUMERO
RewriteRule ^\d+$ post.php?id=$0 [L,QSA]
```

You can replace `R=permanent` by `R=404` or `R=410` to make as if post.php doesn't exist anymore instead of redirecting it.